# Selenium script fails on every step, exception "noSuchElementFound"

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

The Reason for this issues is  the website page not loaded fully. Elements are visible and even clickable but loading message other fly messages doesn't allow to any action on the webpage. I already implemented all type of wait, still few steps keeps on failing. Is there any wait which check page is loaded or not? Using serenity framework.

Comment: add implicit or explicit wait

Comment: Yes, I used both the wait still sometime it doesn't work. So I was looking for something which wait until the whole page is loaded then perform the actions.

Comment: For my personal experience, the wait methods provided by framework does not work reliably in some case. 
Therefore, you can write your own wait method by simple while-loop to return the targeted element after an interval.